# Show whole of image on screen in any orientation

Tags: firefox-for-android

I'm using Firefox version 44.0.2 on the Galaxy Note 4. I cannot zoom out enough to view the whole of images on the screen - so I have to scroll to get a glimpse.

It seems the image is zoomed to fit the height of the phone in portrait mode and zoomed to the width with the phone in landscape mode. End result is I cannot ever see the whole image at once.

For testing I used [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10BfH.jpg).

Attempted solutions:

- I have tried to change a few of the zoom-settings such as `browser.zoom.full`, `toolkit.zoomManager.zoomValues`, and `zoom.minPercent` in `about:config`, to no avail.
- I have also tried disabling all add-ons.
- With an image ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khGa8.jpg)) with 16/9 aspect ratio and the add-on "Full screen mobile", I can actually see the whole image.

So how to make it show the whole image on the screen, no matter how you hold the phone?

In general it would be nice to have kind of indefinite zoom in and zoom out on all content on the web - both images and web pages.

Comment: With Chrome 48 on my Android 5.1.1 OnePlus One, I'm seeing the same problem. But I can scroll, instead of zooming out.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Can you confirm this happens only with Firefox?

Comment: As far as I can tell the built in browser, Dolphin, and Maxthon all have the same problem. Firefox ftw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to do this?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Perhaps this?

[image: IMG:]

Turned out that the config [`browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) controls the behavior you want to change.

- **True**: When viewing an image not in a web page, the image will be resized to fit in the browser window if it is too large for the browser window.
- **False** (default in Firefox for Android): Images are always shown in their real size.

Toggle that setting to `true` in config editor.

For users new to the Firefox config entries: type `about:config` in URL bar, agree for whatever it asks for, type `browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing` in search field and toggle the entry to `true`.

*There is more here*. You can search for the config entry `browser.enable_click_image_resizing`. Toggle it. Now, the effects are identical to previous config entry except that whenever you would single tap on the image, its original size would load. When you tap on original size, the image will be re-sized to fit the page width. Convenient, I suppose.

*One more*. The config entry `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` can also achieve what the first config entry can, but it requires efforts to pin pinpoint the value specific to your device and it would mess up with view of your pages. Nonetheless, it can do the job.

**Note:** Tested on Firefox for Android v44.0.2

Comment: I have tested it, and this is exactly what I needed. I have to say: nice find and good answer! And thank you - I really appreciate it! Unfortunately I am too new here to vote your answer up - someone else please do it for me :-) I did however mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No problem. It was fun answering, given that you did put efforts into your question to solve it.